# Header and Footer does not show on second page (scrlttr2)

Tags: koma-script

i wanted to create a formal letter but the header and the footer does not appear on the other pages than the first one

My Document looks like this:

```
\include{absender.lco}
\documentclass[%
  fontsize=12pt, % Schriftgröße
  version=last%  % Neueste Version von KOMA-Skript verwenden
]{scrlttr2}

% ===== Deutsche Sprache =====
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
% ============================

\LoadLetterOption{DIN} % Einstellungen für DIN 676 laden

\LoadLetterOption{absender} % Absenderdaten und -einstellungen aus absender.lco laden

% ================ Dokumentbegin ================

\setkomavar{signature}{Max Mustermann}%Verfasser

% ================ Dokumentbegin ================

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{%
% ===== Zielanschrift =====
  Erika Musterfrau\\
  Musterweg 43\\
  56789 Musterhausen%
% =======================
}

% ====== Geschäftszeichenzeile =========
\setkomavar{yourref}{ }          % Ihr Zeichen
\setkomavar{yourmail}{ }         % Ihr Schreiben vom
\setkomavar{myref}{ }            % Unser Zeichen
\setkomavar{customer}{ }         % Kundennummer
\setkomavar{invoice}{ }          % Rechnungsnummer
\setkomavar{place}{Gerestried} % Ort
\setkomavar{date}{\today}       % Datum
% =====================================

\setkomavar{title}{Titel}

\setkomavar{subject}{Betreff}

\opening{Sehr geehrte Frau Musterfrau,}

hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. hier kommt der Text hin. 

\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}

% ===== Postskriptum =====
\ps PS: \dots
% ========================

% ===== Anlage(n) =====
% \setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Anlage}
\encl{%
  Anlage 1\\
  Anlage 2%
}
% ===================

% ===== Verteiler =====
% \setkomavar*{ccseparator}{Kopie an}
\cc{%
  Verteiler 1\\
  Verteiler 2%
}
% =====================

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

and my .lco looks like this:

```
\ProvidesFile{absender.lco}

\KOMAoptions{%
% fromemail=true,       % Email wird im Briefkopf angezeigt
% fromphone=true,       % Telefonnumer wird im Briefkopf angezeigt
% fromfax=true,         % Faxnummer wird im Briefkopf angezeit
% fromurl=true,         % URL wird im Briefkopf angezeigt
% fromlogo=true,        % Logo wird im Briefkopf angezeigt
% subject=titled,       % Druckt "Betrifft: " vor dem Betreff
locfield=wide,          % Breite Absenderergänzung (location)
fromalign=left,         % Ausrichtung des Briefkopfes
fromrule=afteraddress%  % Trennlinie unter dem Briefkopf
}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}

\setkomavar{fromname}{NAME} % Name
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{
Adress
}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{belsiptelefonnummer} % Telefonnummer
\setkomavar{fromfax}{belsibfaxnummer} % Faxnummer
\setkomavar{fromemail}{beispiel email} % Email-Adresse
\setkomavar{fromurl}[Website:~]{website} % Website
\newcommand{\chiefexecutive}{CE}%Vorstandsvorsitzender

% ===== Absenderergänzung =====
\setkomavar{location}{%
  \raggedright\footnotesize{%
  \usekomavar{fromname}\\
  \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
  \usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}\\
  \usekomavar*{fromfax}\usekomavar{fromfax}\\
  \usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}
  \usekomavar*{fromurl}\usekomavar{fromurl}}%
}
% ============================


% ===== Abrufbarkeitsergänzung =====

\newcommand{\fromname}{\usekomavar{fromname}} 

% ============================


% ================ Logo ================
%\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\includegraphics{logo.png}}

% ================ Header ================

\makeatletter
\@setplength{firstheadhpos}{0mm}
\@setplength{firstheadvpos}{0mm}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\headbox}{
\usekomafont{pagenumber}
\includegraphics[height=3.7cm]{head.png}}
\firsthead{\headbox}
\nexthead{\headbox}

% ================ Footer ================
\makeatletter
\@setplength{firstfoothpos}{0mm}
\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{260mm}
\makeatother

%\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\includegraphics[height=3.7cm]{foot.png}}

\newcommand*{\footbox}{
\usekomafont{pagenumber}
\begin{overpic}[height=3.7cm]{foot.png}

 \put (18,11) {\Large \textcolor{white}\fromname}

 \put (12,6.5){\tiny \color{white}\usekomavar{frombank}}

 \put (6,5.3){\tiny\color{white} \usekomavar{stnr} 
 \usekomavar{regnr}}

 \put (25,4.1){ \tiny \color{white} \textbf{Verteten druch: }\chiefexecutive}

\end{overpic}}
\firstfoot{\footbox}
\nextfoot{\footbox}


% ================ Bankverbindung ================

% Die Bankverbindung wird nicht automatisch verwendet. Dazu muss bspw. mittels \firstfoot ein eigener Brieffuß definiert werden.
\newkomavar[Steuernummer]{stnr}
\newkomavar[Registernummer]{regnr}

\setkomavar{frombank}{BANKING}
\setkomavar{stnr}{STNR}
\setkomavar{regnr}{REGNR }

% ================ Signatur ================
\setkomavar{signature}{%
  \fromname \\
  Vorstandvorsitzender\\%
  \begin{overpic}[height=1cm]{sign.png} 
  \put(0,0){\small \chiefexecutive}
\end{overpic}
}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}
% ====================

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot

\setlength{\headsep}{4.5cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{8in}

% ================ Dokumentoptionen ================

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\co}{$\mathrm{^c\!/\!_o}$}
```

gz
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will only answer the question how to get a header and footer on the second page in a letter using the `scrlttr2` class. So I remove all the not related stuff from the code.

The default page style of the first page in a KOMA-Script letter is `empty`. So the layout of this page is defined in a completly different way using pseudolength, options and the variables `firsthead` and `firstfoot`. Normally first page header and footer have an other width and an other position as the headers on the following pages.

If you want to use the KOMA-Script variables `nexthead` and `nextfoot` to set the header and footer of the second page, you have to use either page style `headings` or page style `myheadings`. Both are provided by the class.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{absender.lco}
\ProvidesFile{absender.lco}
\setkomavar{fromname}{NAME}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Adress}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{\parbox{\linewidth}{\fbox{my letter header}}}
\setkomavar{nexthead}{\usekomavar{firsthead}}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\parbox{\linewidth}{\fbox{my letter footer}}}
\setkomavar{nextfoot}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\LoadLetterOption{absender} % Laden von absender.lco
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{%
      Erika Musterfrau\\
      Musterweg 43\\
      56789 Musterhausen%
    }
    \setkomavar{title}{Titel}
    \setkomavar{subject}{Betreff}
    \opening{Sehr geehrte Frau Musterfrau,}
    \Blindtext 
    \closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is also possible to use page style `scrheadings` defined by the outdated package `scrpage2` or its successor `scrlayer-scrpage`. But then you have to use the commands of these packages like `\ihead` etc. to define the contents of header and footer. Note that `scrlayer-scrpage` automatically set `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` and redefines page style `headings` as an alias of `scrheadings`.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\LoadLetterOption{absender} % Absenderdaten und -einstellungen aus absender.lco laden
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ihead{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ifoot{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{%
      Erika Musterfrau\\
      Musterweg 43\\
      56789 Musterhausen%
    }
    \setkomavar{title}{Titel}
    \setkomavar{subject}{Betreff}
    \opening{Sehr geehrte Frau Musterfrau,}
    \Blindtext 
    \closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Some additional remarks:

Do not use `\include{absender.lco}`. Load this file either by `\documentclass[...,absender,...]{scrlttr2}` or by `\LoadLetterOption{absender}`. The lco file `DIN` is loaded by the class automatically.

Use `\setkomavar{firsthead}` etc. instead of \firsthead etc.